QGIS Python version 3.9.5 + NumPy 1.20.1 on Mac (Apple Silicon) - Insufficient for plugin
I've been trying to get a QGIS plugin to work and running into trouble. The plugin's developer (plugin: Qaequilibrae) has told me that the Python version (3.9.5) and especially NumPy version (1.20.1) shipping with QGIS on my machine (MacOS 14.0, Apple silicon M1) are not compatible with the plugin.
Is there anything that can be done in this case?
Can a more up-to-date version of Python/NumPy be used with QGIS?

As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

You can install qgis in an anaconda environment from conda-forge or possibly from homebrew rather than using the prepackaged dmg. Then you can use any python and package versions you want.  You can also go to the QGIS Mac packaging repo and add your voice to calls to update the packaging.

Thank you very much for your help
